# CListBox's Item size changed when changing the size of the list box even if I specify the size in MeasureItem() method?

Tags: mfc, ownerdrawn, clistbox

I used a class which derives from `CListBox`, and create it with following:

```
style:WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE |LBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED | WS_VSCROLL | WS_HSCROLL
```

I expect the ListBox's item to be have a fixed size, not affected by the size of the list box. So I override the MeasureItem() method, in which I specify the item's size like below:

```
void CMyListBox::MeasureItem(LPMEASUREITEMSTRUCT lpMIS)
{
    lpMIS->itemHeight = ALBUM_ITEM_HEIGHT;
    lpMIS->itemWidth = ALBUM_ITEM_WIDTH;
}
```

But the item's size changes according to the List box's size changing. is there anything wrong with my approach?

Answer (score 1):

What's not mentioned in the reference is that `WM_MEASUREITEM` is called *every time* the `*_OWNERDRAWFIXED` control is resized.

I don't know however, how official this behavior is and whether it should be relied on, but it has been verified at [CodeGuru](http://www.codeguru.com/Cpp/controls/listview/advanced/article.php/c1013) and several forum posts found on the Google thing.

If you don't want to process the message, then just set a private flag somewhere in the first `OnMeasureItem()` call and return from it as soon as you check that it's set next time.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the `MSDN` entry for [`CListBox::MeasureItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t7tccyw7(VS.80).aspx) you'll see that it's only called once unless the `LBS_OWNERDRAWVARIABLE` (not `LBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED`) style is set. If I understand correctly then this would explain the behaviour you're seeing because `MeasureItem` would need to be called each time the control's size changes.

Also, have you considered the points made in [MFC Technical Note 14 : Custom Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bk2h3c6w(VS.80).aspx)?